# vb.net connection through ssh tunnel

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ssh

I have a basic application which writte and read some data from database.
A basic mysql connection string is which I'm usually using is:

```
 MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=xxxx;userid=xxxx;password=xxxx;database=xxxx;"
```

When I purchased a new host for my website, I didn't saw that for shared hosting, they provide only mysql connection through ssh tunneling, not remote mysql, so basically, my connectionstring I used is not working anymore.

My question is: Can someone provide code to connect to my database through ssh tunnel?

Comment: What have you tried and what problems dod you have? Did you get any errors that could help?

Comment: Basically, it gives that it can't connect to mysql server. I asked support from that site (which is namecheap) and they said that for shared hosting, they don't offer remote mysql connection, only ssh tunnel mysql connection. Also I used mysql workbench to edit my databases. I tried with it (without ssh tunnel) and I got same error with can't connect to mysql server. After using ssh tunnel like live chat said, I was able to successfull connect to my database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL connection string through SSH tunnel without password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498955/mysql-connection-string-through-ssh-tunnel-without-password)

Comment: it's in C#, I need visual basic code :(, and I'm not so good at converting from C# to VB.

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh port forwarding.

From Linux or OSX you can do it from the terminal or if you are running Windows use Putty client. Guess you are running Windows if you are developing VB.NET. :)

An example [here](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html).

Comment: Well, this app will be used as a marketplace for customers, so I can't ask all my customers to do that ssh port forwarding. That's why I want to integrate this ssh tunnel into my app code.